Xamarin Forms - Sound In taken by another service
I am in an undesirable situation where I need a fix to an outdated Xamarin Forms application, that cannot be updated immediately but I need a hotfix in the interim.
When a call is answered and the device goes off the hook is there any examples of how to register to this and stop anything using the microphone? We have audio capture which is silent during the call and I'd like to register to off the hook to stop.
I have done some research around Android and TelephonyManager and PhoneStateListener however I have not been able to get this to fire when a call is taken. I need to find a solution for xamarin forms 5.0 in both Android and Windows
